# UWP Canvas Pixel Manipulation

Tags: windows, xaml, uwp, c++-cx

I managed to create a canvas and a user can draw on it using [this Microsoft example](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SimpleInk).

**Now I want to count the number of white and black pixels. And also modify colors of some of the pixels.**

I could not find any example on how to get all the pixel data from canvas and manipulate and update it.

```
<Page
    x:Class="SDKTemplate.Scenario1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    SizeChanged="OnSizeChanged"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Margin="12,10,12,12">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,10">
                <TextBlock Text="Description:" Style="{StaticResource SampleHeaderTextStyle}"/>
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ScenarioDescriptionTextStyle}" TextWrapping="Wrap">
                This scenario adds an InkCanvas and InkToolbar to the page.<LineBreak/>
                    - Use either pen or mouse to ink.<LineBreak/>
                    - A chevron glyph on the active tool button indicates that additional settings are available in a flyout. Select the active tool once more to display the flyout.
                </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
            <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollMode="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <InkToolbar Grid.Row="0" TargetInkCanvas="{x:Bind inkCanvas}"/>
                    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" x:Name="scrollViewer" ZoomMode="Enabled" MinZoomFactor="1" VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                        <Grid x:Name="outputGrid" Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundChromeWhiteBrush}" Height="Auto">
                            <!-- Inking area -->
                            <InkCanvas x:Name="inkCanvas" Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Grid>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "Scenario1.xaml.h"
#include "SampleConfiguration.h"

using namespace SDKTemplate;

using namespace Platform;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Windows::Foundation::Collections;
using namespace Windows::UI::Core;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls;

Scenario1::Scenario1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Initialize the InkCanvas
    inkCanvas->InkPresenter->InputDeviceTypes =
        CoreInputDeviceTypes::Mouse |
        CoreInputDeviceTypes::Pen;


}


void Scenario1::OnSizeChanged(Object^ sender, SizeChangedEventArgs^ e)
{
    HelperFunctions::UpdateCanvasSize(RootGrid, outputGrid, inkCanvas);
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You could get a GIF image to get the pixel data in the **Scenario3** of the linked sample. Or, you could use [InkStrokeContainer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Input.Inking.InkStrokeContainer?view=winrt-19041) class to manage the collection of `InkStroke` objects, referring to the **Scenario4** of the linked sample.

Comment: if i use gif to get the pixel data and manipulate it. how should i update the canvas again? because i am trying to implement flood fill algorithm.

Comment: In the **Scenario3** of the sample, `inkCanvas` gets stream from the selected gif file. The gif file is saved from the `inkCanvas`. I tried to do some changes in the gif file and read the file into `inkCanvas` by using [InkStrokeContainer.LoadAsync(IInputStream)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.inking.inkstrokecontainer.loadasync?view=winrt-19041) method, it failed.

Comment: Therefore, I thought you could try to show the changed gif file into an Image control. Note to put the Image control an InkCanvas into the same container and add the Image control first. If this way could meet your requirements and you need, I can show you the code as a sample.

Comment: can you please show a code example, it would make a lot more sense for me. thank you

Answer (score 0):

The following code is based on the code in **Scenario3** of the linked sample:

Put an `Image` control into the same container as `InkCanvas` in `Scenario3.xaml`. Note to add the `Image` control in the front of `InkCanvas` control.

```
<Grid x:Name="outputGrid" Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundChromeWhiteBrush}">
    <!-- Inking area -->
    <Image x:Name="inkImage" Stretch="None"/>
    <InkCanvas x:Name="inkCanvas">
    </InkCanvas>
</Grid>
```

In `Scenario3.xaml.cpp` file, find the `OnLoadAsync` method. Comment or delete the original `return` statement and add a new one:

```
void Scenario3::OnLoadAsync(Object^ sender, RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    auto openPicker = ref new FileOpenPicker();
    openPicker->SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId::PicturesLibrary;
    openPicker->FileTypeFilter->Append(".gif");
    openPicker->FileTypeFilter->Append(".isf");

    create_task(openPicker->PickSingleFileAsync()).then([this](StorageFile^ file)
    {
        if (file != nullptr)
        {
            return create_task(file->OpenAsync(Windows::Storage::FileAccessMode::Read)).then([this](IRandomAccessStream^ fileStream)
            {
                // Set the image source to the selected bitmap
                auto bitmapImage = ref new BitmapImage();
                bitmapImage->SetSource(fileStream);
                inkImage->Source = bitmapImage;
            });

        }
        else
        {
            return task_from_result();
        }
    });
}
```

Note that changed images are shown in `Image` control, and you couldn’t save images again by the **Save** button which is used to save inks of `InkCanvas` in **Scenario3**.